# Using mapply to divide lists of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, mapply

I have the following data.

```
set.seed(12345)

df1z <- matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=10, ncol=10)
df2z <- df1z
dfZ <- list(df1z, df2z)

df1x <- matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=10, ncol=1)
df2x <- df1x
dfX <- list(df1x, df2x)
```

I basically want to perform the following set operations, except use mapply.

```
A1 = t(t(df1z)/as.vector(df1x))
A2 = t(t(df2z)/as.vector(df2x))
```

When I try the following, I get an empty list.

```
mapply(function(a, b) return(t(t(a)/b), dfZ, dfX, SIMPLIFY=F))
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please use `set.seed` while generating random numbers so that we can reproduce the same numbers at our end. Instead of having 10 X 10 matrix can you post a 2 X 2 matrix with the expected output?

Comment: The datasets are not of the same size.  Did you meant `df4 <- df3` and `Map(function(a, b) a/b[col(a)], dfZ, dfX)`

Comment: Or it could be `Map(function(a, b) a/b[,1], dfZ, dfX)` or `Map(function(a, b) a/b[row(a)], dfZ, dfX)`

Comment: I've updated the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are misplaced.  If we fix that and add `as.vector` then it gives the same as `A1` and `A2`.   Also, although not necessary for it to work as desired, in order to streamline it a bit we have eliminated the unnecessary `return` and used `Map` instead of `mapply` -- `Map` is similar to `mapply` but does not simplify.

```
ans <- Map(function(a, b) t(t(a)/as.vector(b)), dfZ, dfX)
identical(ans, list(A1, A2))
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We could just replicate the 'b' to make the lengths equal and then do the division

```
ans1 <- Map(function(a, b) a/b[col(a)], dfZ, dfX)
identical(ans1, list(A1, A2))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
ans2 <- map2(dfZ, dfX, ~ .x/.y[,1][col(.x)])
identical(ans2, list(A1, A2))
#[1] TRUE
```